# Magento 2 : Calling a JS function from another JS file?

Tags: javascript, frontend, knockoutjs, tax, html

This [Accessing a JS function from another JS file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227485/accessing-a-js-function-from-another-js-file?rq=1)  solution  not mapped on my problem ,Please give me direction that how can i call **getPureValue: function ()** from tax.js into some where in minicart.js

> tax.js

```
 /**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */

define([
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
    'mage/translate',
    'underscore'
], function (ko, Component, quote, totals, $t, _) {
    'use strict';

    var isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal = window.checkoutConfig.includeTaxInGrandTotal,
        isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed = window.checkoutConfig.isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed,
        isZeroTaxDisplayed = window.checkoutConfig.isZeroTaxDisplayed,
        taxAmount = 0,
        rates = 0;

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal: isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal,
            notCalculatedMessage: $t('Not yet calculated'),
            template: 'Magento_Tax/checkout/summary/tax'
        },
        totals: quote.getTotals(),
        isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed: isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed,

        /**
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        ifShowValue: function () {
            if (this.isFullMode() && this.getPureValue() == 0) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                return isZeroTaxDisplayed;
            }

            return true;
        },

        /**
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        ifShowDetails: function () {
            if (!this.isFullMode()) {
                return false;
            }

            return this.getPureValue() > 0 && isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed;
        },

        /**
         * @return {Number}
         */
        getPureValue: function () {
            var amount = 0,
                taxTotal;

            if (this.totals()) {
                taxTotal = totals.getSegment('tax');

                if (taxTotal) {
                    amount = taxTotal.value;
                }
            }
            console.log(amount);
                console.log('getPureValue');
            return amount;
        },

        /**
         * @return {*|Boolean}
         */
        isCalculated: function () {
             console.log('isCalculated');
            return this.totals() && this.isFullMode() && totals.getSegment('tax') != null;
        },

        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        getValue: function () {
            var amount;
             console.log('getValue');
             console.log(amount);
            if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                return this.notCalculatedMessage;
            }
            amount = totals.getSegment('tax').value;

            return this.getFormattedPrice(amount);
        },

        /**
         * @param {*} amount
         * @return {*|String}
         */
        formatPrice: function (amount) {
            return this.getFormattedPrice(amount);
        },

        /**
         * @param {*} parent
         * @param {*} percentage
         * @return {*|String}
         */
        getTaxAmount: function (parent, percentage) {
            var totalPercentage = 0;
 console.log('getTaxAmount');
            taxAmount = parent.amount;
            rates = parent.rates;
            _.each(rates, function (rate) {
                totalPercentage += parseFloat(rate.percent);
            });

            return this.getFormattedPrice(this.getPercentAmount(taxAmount, totalPercentage, percentage));
        },

        /**
         * @param {*} amount
         * @param {*} totalPercentage
         * @param {*} percentage
         * @return {*|String}
         */
        getPercentAmount: function (amount, totalPercentage, percentage) {
             console.log('getPercentAmount');
            return parseFloat(amount * percentage / totalPercentage);
        },

        /**
         * @return {Array}
         */
        getDetails: function () {
            var taxSegment = totals.getSegment('tax');
 console.log('getDetails');
            if (taxSegment && taxSegment['extension_attributes']) {
                return taxSegment['extension_attributes']['tax_grandtotal_details'];
            }

            return [];
        }
    });
});
```

> minicart.js

```
 /**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'sidebar',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/dropdown'
], function (Component, customerData,$, ko, _) {
    'use strict';

    var sidebarInitialized = false,
        addToCartCalls = 0,
        miniCart;

    miniCart = $('[data-block=\'minicart\']');

    /**
     * @return {Boolean}
     */
    function initSidebar() {
        if (miniCart.data('mageSidebar')) {
            miniCart.sidebar('update');
        }

        if (!$('[data-role=product-item]').length) {
            return false;
        }
        miniCart.trigger('contentUpdated');

        if (sidebarInitialized) {
            return false;
        }
        sidebarInitialized = true;
        miniCart.sidebar({
            'targetElement': 'div.block.block-minicart',
            'url': {
                'checkout': window.checkout.checkoutUrl,
                'update': window.checkout.updateItemQtyUrl,
                'remove': window.checkout.removeItemUrl,
                'loginUrl': window.checkout.customerLoginUrl,
                'isRedirectRequired': window.checkout.isRedirectRequired
            },
            'button': {
                'checkout': '#top-cart-btn-checkout',
                'remove': '#mini-cart a.action.delete',
                'close': '#btn-minicart-close'
            },
            'showcart': {
                'parent': 'span.counter',
                'qty': 'span.counter-number',
                'label': 'span.counter-label'
            },
            'minicart': {
                'list': '#mini-cart',
                'content': '#minicart-content-wrapper',
                'qty': 'div.items-total',
                'subtotal': 'div.subtotal span.price',
                'maxItemsVisible': window.checkout.minicartMaxItemsVisible
            },
            'item': {
                'qty': ':input.cart-item-qty',
                'button': ':button.update-cart-item'
            },
            'confirmMessage': $.mage.__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?')
        });
    }

    miniCart.on('dropdowndialogopen', function () {
        initSidebar();
    });

    return Component.extend({
        shoppingCartUrl: window.checkout.shoppingCartUrl,
        maxItemsToDisplay: window.checkout.maxItemsToDisplay,
        cart: {},

        // jscs:disable requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers
        /**
         * @override
         */
        initialize: function () {
            var self = this,
                cartData = customerData.get('cart');

            this.update(cartData());
            cartData.subscribe(function (updatedCart) {
                addToCartCalls--;
                this.isLoading(addToCartCalls > 0);
                sidebarInitialized = false;
                this.update(updatedCart);
                initSidebar();
            }, this);
            $('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentLoading', function () {
                addToCartCalls++;
                self.isLoading(true);
            });

            if (
                cartData().website_id !== window.checkout.websiteId && cartData().website_id !== undefined ||
                cartData().storeId !== window.checkout.storeId && cartData().storeId !== undefined
            ) {
                customerData.reload(['cart'], false);
            }

            return this._super();
        },


        //jscs:enable requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers

        isLoading: ko.observable(false),
        initSidebar: initSidebar,

        /**
         * Close mini shopping cart.
         */
        closeMinicart: function () {
            $('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog('close');
        },


        /**
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        closeSidebar: function () {
            var minicart = $('[data-block="minicart"]');

            minicart.on('click', '[data-action="close"]', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                minicart.find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog('close');
            });

            return true;
        },


        /**
         * @param {String} productType
         * @return {*|String}
         */
        getItemRenderer: function (productType) {
            return this.itemRenderer[productType] || 'defaultRenderer';
        },

        /**
         * Update mini shopping cart content.
         *
         * @param {Object} updatedCart
         * @returns void
         */
        update: function (updatedCart) {
            console.log('helloworld');
            _.each(updatedCart, function (value, key) {
                if (!this.cart.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    this.cart[key] = ko.observable();
                }
                this.cart[key](value);
            }, this);
        },

        /**
         * Get cart param by name.
         * @param {String} name
         * @returns {*}
         */
        getCartParam: function (name) {
            if (!_.isUndefined(name)) {
                if (!this.cart.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                    this.cart[name] = ko.observable();
                }
            }
console.log('helloworld');
            return this.cart[name]();

        },

        /**
         * Returns array of cart items, limited by 'maxItemsToDisplay' setting
         * @returns []
         */
        getCartItems: function () {
            var items = this.getCartParam('items') || [];

            items = items.slice(parseInt(-this.maxItemsToDisplay, 10));
console.log('helloworld');
            return items;
        },

        /**
         * Returns count of cart line items
         * @returns {Number}
         */
        getCartLineItemsCount: function () {
            var items = this.getCartParam('items') || [];

            return parseInt(items.length, 10);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add tax.js into require of minicart.js, `Magento_Checkout/js/model/total` and `Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote`

```
// minicart.js

define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'sidebar',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/dropdown'
], function (Component, customerData, totals, quote, $, ko, _) {
    var getPureValue = function () {
        var amount = 0,
            taxTotal;

        if (quote.getTotals()) {
            taxTotal = totals.getSegment('tax');

            if (taxTotal) {
                amount = taxTotal.value;
            }
        }
        return amount;
    };
    console.log(getPureValue());
});
```

Comment: After doing this ,how then we call  **getPureValue()** function

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulah tax.getPureValue()

Comment: after define 
'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/tax'
 got error ,
any idea

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulah I fixed this issue, the view js can not include directly. sorry ~